# Run individual Detox test

Tags: detox

Running `detox test` runs all tests in the suite. Is there a way to run a subset of the tests? A single test file, or a single test case.

I've configured Detox to use Mocha as the test runner, as per the docs. I know that Mocha has a `-g` option to specify a pattern for the tests to run. But options passed to the `detox` command don't seem to be passed along to `mocha`:

```
# detox test -g mytestcase

error: unknown option `-g'
```

I'm attempting to use Detox for TDD, and the quicker the feedback I can get, the better. As my test suite grows, it would become less and less motivating to run tests as I develop if the time to run gets longer and longer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Edit: Turns out you don't need the `-f` flag at all.

You can just do `detox test /path/to/yourTest.spec.js` and it works for single files (tested on v14.4.1).

[Source](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Guide.Migration.md#migrating-from-detox-120x-to-121x)

<s>I ended up using the `-f` parameter for testing a specific test.</s>

`detox test -f /path/to/yourTest.spec.js`

Came across it from the [repo](https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/536#issuecomment-449463597). Looks like it may have been updated.

Answer (score 6):

**Preface:**

Detox is test runner agnostic, you can actually use which ever test runner you want. The only thing we did is try to make dev life easier by creating `detox-cli`, which currently only works with mocha and jest, but you can easily extend it to any other runner.
While I agree the implementation of `detox-cli` is not perfect (params are not being passthrough from to test runner, and generally it needs a bit of work), its pretty easy to add whatever you want in [detox-test.js](https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/detox/local-cli/detox-test.js).

**Actual answer:**

In the meantime, the fastest way to to run individual test is by using `only` to to mark the suites/tests you want to run: `describe.only` and `it.only`.

Comment: Jest: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/api.html#describeonlyname-fn


Mocha: https://mochajs.org/#exclusive-tests

Answer (score 2):

**Consider the following code for running particular suite**

```
describe.only('App screen', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
        await device.reloadReactNative();
    });
```

In the above code  "Only" will run the whole test suite.

**Consider the following code for running particular test case**

```
it.only('should write into TextInputs', async () => {
            await element(by.id("input")).typeText("Detox Automation POC-Test for enter text and delete text");
            await element(by.id("input")).clearText();
            await element(by.id("input")).replaceText("Bye");
```

In the above code  "Only" will run the particular test case.

Comment: This will only run signle describe in one file, but will still run other tests in different file. You need to use it in combination with `detox test /path/to/yourTest.spec.js`.

Comment: @Townsheriff The question is asked about running an individual detox test and does not mention whether to run in a single file or not so the answer is right don't interpret it to confuse others :)

Answer (score 1):

workaround can be helpfull. Did it also for ssh-channel to remote host with detox through ssh:

1. create another folder for tests (not e2e, f.E. "temp-tests") on the same folder-structure level.
2. copy all your tests to temp-tests
3. write small script and start it from "e2e" folder. It will :

   delete all tests in e2e, then will take only one test from
   "temp-tests" and put it to "e2e" folder and start it.

4 (optional) also one can write saving of mocha-report into another file for each test for reporting issues.

script:
////////////////////////////////////////////
rm *.spec.js 
cd ../run-tests
cp  *unique-testname* ../e2e/
detox test --configuration yourapp.initial